# Yammer: Android WebView Authentication

Tags: android, yammer

I am trying to authenticate an user from my Android App for Yammer OAuth. Using Webview for loading the authentication URL and expecting a code / token to come back. But the results are not predictable.

```
webView.loadUrl(OAUTH_URL + "?redirect_uri=" + REDIRECT_URI + "&client_id=" + CLIENT_ID);
```

Also using WebViewClient.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {...}
```

In Android 4.4, no URL redirection is happening and it stays blank. Or no code / token comes.

In older android versions, it works sporadically.

Anyone tried this? I am doing this because of the lack of Android SDK. Appreciate any working sample.

Adding Android tag to reach bigger group. Any working snippet is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goodness gracious, after hours and hours of struggle, finally fixed it.

Problem is I was having the WebView load into a dialog, instead of a full activity. Thats it! The WebView inside a Dialog was loading redirects so unpredictably.

As soon as moved the WebView into its own Activity which has layout height and width of fill_parent, everything worked the way it is supposed to work.